# Is there something to send data from java class to another java class?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I was trying to make a registration page that takes two infos

The registration is like this: you enter 3 information and you click the "next" button to go to another page and enter the personal data then submit

but the problem is I can't get the account info to save it into the database

I am using struts2

the first page just check if the username or email has duplicate, if it has then the action class will return "failed" then refresh the page. If it doesn't have dups then it will go to the second page.

is there something like httpsession?

here's my code

```
    checkEmail vMail = new checkEmail();
    checkUser vUser = new checkUser();
    int mailCount = vMail.dba(email);
    int userCount = vUser.dba(username);

            if(mailCount == 0){
               if(userCount == 0){
                   try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/march4","root",sc.pass);

        String add = ("INSERT INTO accountdata VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(add);
        st.setInt(1, 0);
        st.setString(2, getUsername());
        st.setString(3, getPassword());
        st.setString(4, getEmail());

        st.executeUpdate();
        st.close();
        con.close();
        return "success";
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        return "failed";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return "failed";
    }


                }else{return "failed";}
            }else{return "failed";}
```

And here's the code for my second action class

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/march4","root",sc.pass);
        String user = ("SELECT username FROM accountdata WHERE password ="+getCpassword());
        Statement state = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(user);
        username = rs.getString(user);
        String mail = ("SELECT email FROM accountdata WHERE password ="+getCpassword());
        ResultSet rs2 = state.executeQuery(mail);
        email = rs2.getString(mail);
```

I have private String username and password
and did I use the correct syntax for mysql?
I have two tables and I use the password and confirm password for the key

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think you need just to redirect your page, in case of success you can read this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_redirect_action.htm) here i think it can help you.

Comment: How can you search by only password two users may have same password, pass one more parameter with password then only you will get unique result

Comment: it looks a bit odd: your vMail.dba(email); checks the variabel "email" but our preparedStatement uses the method getEmail(); it isnt really very good, I cant tell if you are actually checking the right variable.

Comment: the vMail.dba checks if the email has duplicate. its another class


yeah I having problems what unique parameter besides password

Comment: password should not be unique. normally multiple users can have the same password, just not the same username.
but what i ment was that you check that the variable email does not already exist, and then you insert getEmail() this may very well refence the same variable but it is unclear with the provided code sample.

Comment: Apart from the issue of the duplicate e-mail, if you are trying to build a wizard-like form (2 steps) you need some kind of persistence. If you want to use `sessions` take a look to the Struts2 `Scope Interceptor`: http://struts.apache.org/docs/scope-interceptor.html